# scala claims JAVA_HOME is incorrect

Tags: asdf-vm

System is Ubuntu 20 on WSL2.
asdf version: 0.8.1 installed with brew

As seen below, I can execute `java` and `sbt`, but `scala` claims the `JAVA_HOME` is incorrect.

```
~> java --version
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)

~> sbt --version
sbt version in this project: 1.5.5
sbt script version: 1.5.5

~> scala --version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /home/craig/.asdf/shims/bin/java

~> echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/craig/.asdf/shims

~> ls /home/craig/.asdf/shims
common  jarsigner  javac    javap  jconsole  jdeprscan  jfr    jimage  jlink  jmod      jps         jshell  jstat   keytool  rmiregistry  sbt-launch.jar  sbtn-x86_64-apple-darwin  sbtn-x86_64-pc-win32.exe  scalac    serialver
jar     java       javadoc  jcmd   jdb       jdeps      jhsdb  jinfo   jmap   jpackage  jrunscript  jstack  jstatd  project  sbt          sbt.bat         sbtn-x86_64-pc-linux      scala                     scaladoc  target
~>
```

It would appear that `scala` expects `java` to be in `<shims dir>/bin`, but as shown, there is no `bin`.

I haven't found open issues related to this with `asdf`.  However, if `JAVA_HOME` is incorrect, then `java` and `sbt` should not work either.

So, is this a problem with my system, `asdf` itself or the scala `asdf` plugin, or something else?  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Oh, I think I just found an open issue for this!

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/558

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to [the issue](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/558), but I was able to get going again by creating a symbolic link like this:

```
~> ls -ltr .asdf/shims/bin
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 craig craig 7 Aug 19 18:04 java -> ../java
~>
```